# get the value from force:RecordData on Init handler

Tags: lightning-aura-components, force-recorddata

Is there a way we can get the value from force:RecordData on init ? I am getting the onclick event of a button.

```
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String"/> 
    <aura:attribute name="showButton" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="Opportunity" type="Object"/>   
    <aura:attribute name="parentOpp" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="oppLoadError" type="String"/>
    <force:recordData aura:id="oppRecordLoader"
                      recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                      fields="Id,
                              Name,
                              AccountId,
                              Cohort_Sem__r.End_date__c,
                              LeadSource,
                              Staff_Referral_Detail__c,
                              lead_source_detail__c"
                      targetRecord="{!v.Opportunity}"
                      targetFields="{!v.parentOpp}"
                      targetError="{!v.oppLoadError}"
                      />
```

JS:

```
doInit: function(component, event, helper) {           
         var opp = component.get("v.parentOpp");         
         console.log('Name Value: '+ opp.Name);
    }
```

Error:

> Action failed: c:createIWSRecord$controller$doInit [Cannot read
>   property 'Name' of null] quickActionHandlerHelper.js failed to create
>   component - forceChatter:lightningComponent

Answer (score 23, accepted):

force:recordData handles loading the record(s) asynchronously. As such, it will *not* be available during the init handler (there hasn't been a chance to run asynchronous code yet), and will likely not be available in the first render/afterRender cycle either.

The official method is to use the recordUpdated event.

```
<aura:attribute name="record" type="Asset" />

<force:recordData layoutType="FULL"
                  recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                  targetFields="{!v.record}"
                  recordUpdated="{!c.recordUpdate}" />
```

---

```
({
    recordUpdate: function(component, event, helper) {
        alert(component.get("v.record").Name);
    }
})
```

Comment: You need to add mode for recordUpdated to work:
recordUpdated="{!c.recordLoaded}"
mode="VIEW"

Comment: @DaveRoberts The default mode is VIEW, so it is not necessary to specify it. You will, however, get an error if you specify an invalid mode. I just tested this to confirm the behavior, and it does indeed work here verbatim with no extra attributes.

Comment: You're correct. I also confirmed it. I must have had something else wrong when I came to that conclusion.

Answer (score -2):

I think in Init your Data is not available, Instead of Init, use **render** handler. It seems to be working in render handler.

```
<aura:handler name="render" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
```

Comment: This approach is not reliable: record loading is asynchronous and independent from the rendering cycle. The data may not be available at the first (or second or third) render. Use the recordUpdated event to be notified when the record is loaded.