# How to get other field values than recordId when from aura lightning component used on record page?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura

I have created a aura lightning component which implements `force:hasRecordId`.

```
<force:recordData aura:id="recordLoader" 
                      recordId="{!v.recordId}" 
                      fields="Name, OrderNumber__c, test_field_1__c, test_field_2__c " 
                      targetFields="{!v.opty}" 
                      targetError="{!v.recordLoadError}" />
```

I am using above snippet.

Now, I need to retieve field values of fields like `OrderNumber__c, test_field_1__c, test_field_2__c` in my JS controller without using apex class.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

U can go through the below link:

[URL](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/206686/get-the-value-from-forcerecorddata-on-init-handler)