# Modify this Aura Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, screen-flow, popup

I need a little help that I can't help, I have this aura component, called "ShopSatisfaction Questionnaire", the thing I want is that the popup with the flow only appears in certain when the aura:if is true, at the moment it works that the button appears and then using the button I bring up the popup with the flow, but what if I would like to remove the button and make it appear automatically when the page is loaded?

CMP:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
<aura:attribute name="record" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="simpleRecord" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="recordError" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="showModal" type="Boolean" default="false"/>

<!-- record that we're sitting on -->
<aura:attribute name="recordfields" type="String[]" default="Name,CreatedBy.Name,CreatedDate,OwnerId,Carrelli_Totali__c"/>
<force:recordData aura:id="recordLoader"
                  recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                  targetRecord="{!v.record}"
                  fields="{!v.recordfields}"
                  targetFields="{!v.simpleRecord}"
                  targetError="{!v.recordError}"
                  />
<aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.recordError))}">
    <div class="recordError">
        <ui:message title="Error" severity="error" closable="true">
            {!v.recordError}
        </ui:message>
    </div>
</aura:if>
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.simpleRecord.Carrelli_Totali__c > 11}">
    <label>Totali Carrelli:</label>&nbsp;<ui:outputText value="{!v.simpleRecord.Carrelli_Totali__c}"/><br />
    <div class="slds">
        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showModal}">
            <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
            <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true"
                     class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
                <div class="slds-modal__container">
                    <header class="slds-modal__header">
                        <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse"
                                title="Chiudi" onclick="{!c.closeModal}">
                            <lightning:icon iconName="utility:close" size="small" variant="inverse" />
                            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Chiudi</span>
                        </button>
                        <!--<h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-modal__title slds-hyphenate">Flusso di registrazione</h2>-->
                    </header>
                    <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium">
                        <lightning:flow aura:id="flowData"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </aura:if>
        <aura:if isTrue="{!not(v.showModal)}">
            <lightning:button variant="base" label="Non sei un membro? Registrati" title="Registrati" onclick="{!c.openModal}" class="button-style"/>
            <!--<ui:button label="Non sei un membro? Registrati" press="{!c.openModal}" class="button-style"/>-->
        </aura:if>
    </div>
</aura:if>
```

</aura:component>

JS:

```
({
openModal: function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set("v.showModal", true);
    var flow = component.find("flowData");
    flow.startFlow("Form_di_Registrazione_ScreenFlow");
},
closeModal: function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set("v.showModal", false);
    var flow = component.find("flowData");
    flow.stopFlow();
}
```

})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is relatively simple to achieve. To do this, you need to invoke the logic when the force:recordData component finishes asynchronously loading the record.

This can be achieved by using the `recordUpdated` event that is fired by this component once it's loaded. To use this, you'll need to modify your force:recordData declaration:

```
<force:recordData aura:id="recordLoader"
                  recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                  targetRecord="{!v.record}"
                  fields="{!v.recordfields}"
                  targetFields="{!v.simpleRecord}"
                  targetError="{!v.recordError}"
                  recordUpdated="{!c.handleRecordUpdated}"
                  />
```

From here, you'll need to define the `handleRecordUpdated` function that will contain the logic required.

```
({
    /**
     * Method called when the force:recordData component finishes retrieving or updating the record.
     */
    handleRecordUpdated: function(component, event, helper) {
        
        //Get the total to use in your logic
        var total = component.get("v.simpleRecord").Carrelli_Totali__c;
        //If total meets the conditions (based on your existing component that was shared)
        if(total > 11){
            component.set("v.showModal", true);
            var flow = component.find("flowData");
            flow.startFlow("Form_di_Registrazione_ScreenFlow");
        }
    }
})
```

This is similar to the question/answer here: [get the value from force:RecordData on Init handler](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/206686/get-the-value-from-forcerecorddata-on-init-handler)

Comment: I added what you told me and fixed the component, but when I insert it it gives me this error: This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Assertion Failed!: Unable to get value for key '{c.handleRecordUpdated}'. No value provider was found for '{c'. : false Failing descriptor: {force:recordData}

Comment: I fixed it, the exclamation mark was missing

Comment: Apologies, I've updated that now.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation